python requests get to download csv
header = {
            "Authorization": f"API-Token XXX",
            "Accepts": "text/csv, application/json; q=0.1"
            }
url11=f"https://dynatrace.glb.platform.dxc.com:443/e/xxx/api/v2/metrics/query?metricSelector=(builtin:host.cpu.usage:splitBy(dt.entity.host):avg):limit(2):names&from=2024-11-11T00:10:00Z&to=2024-11-17T23:55:00Z&resolution=Inf" 
resp=requests.get(url11, headers=header,timeout=10)
resp.json 

Again, it is coming as JSON, but when I print it out it is comma separated values (CSV).
How to get output as comma separated values using python requests?
It is executing fine only the output is wrong.

Use the below function I wrote and pass the data as a list of dictionaries to it.
def write_json_response_to_comma_seperated_csv_file(filename: str, data: list) -> None:
    assert isinstance(data, list), "Data must be a list of dictionaries"
    import csv

    if not data:
        print("No data to write to CSV.")
        return

    with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=data[0].keys())
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(data)

    print(f"CSV file created successfully in {filename} !")


data = [
    {'first_name': 'Omid', 'last_name': 'Hashemzadeh', 'gender': 'Male'},
    {'first_name': 'Bill', 'last_name': 'Gates', 'gender': 'Male'},
    {'first_name': 'Marilyn', 'last_name': 'Monroe', 'gender': 'Female'},
]

write_json_response_to_comma_seperated_csv_file("response.csv", data)

response.csv ->
first_name,last_name,gender
Omid,Hashemzadeh,Male
Bill,Gates,Male
Marilyn,Monroe,Female


your last line of code is resp.json?
You can use pandas library to convert json to csv
df = pd.read_json()
df.to_csv()

or check whether dynatrace.glb.platform.dxc.com provides csv to be downloaded.

This may get you closer to your desired output:
import json
from pandas import json_normalize
info = json.loads(resp.json)
fileaction = json_normalize(info)
fileaction.to_csv(filename, index=False, encoding='utf-8')

